# How to subset an Xts matrix in Rcpp based on date and time?

Tags: r

Given I the following basic data:

```
x <- xts(1:1000, as.Date("2000-01-01")+1:1000)
head(x)
           [,1]
2000-01-02    1
2000-01-03    2
2000-01-04    3
2000-01-05    4
2000-01-06    5
2000-01-07    6
```

In R is it very easy to get a smaller data set based on date and time:

```
x.subset <- x["2000-02-05 00:00:00/2000-03-10 00:00:00"]
head(x.subset)
           [,1]
2000-02-05   35
2000-02-06   36
2000-02-07   37
2000-02-08   38
2000-02-09   39
2000-02-10   40
```

The question how can I do this type of subsetting directly in Rcpp?

**Update**
As Dirk mentioned extracting based on time is difficult, but I cannot even subset properly with just index.
What did work:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject subsetRcpp(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& x)
{
  return wrap(x(1,_));
}
```

This just returns 2 which is the second row or value of my sample vector.

```
return wrap(x(_,0));
```

Returns the entire vector or column, but my biggest problem is that it only has the data and strips the XTS index and other attributes. Where I expect the equivalent of **x[,1]** in R.

If I try getting a Range as in the documentation using:
return wrap(x(y.begin(), y.end());
return wrap(x( Range(0,0), Range(0,5));
I have a compile error such as:
`no match for call to '(Const NumericMAtrix {aka const Rcpp::Matrix,14.}) (Rcpp::Range, Rcpp::Range)'` or
`no match for call to '(Const NumericMAtrix {aka const Rcpp::Matrix,14.}) (Rcpp::const_iterator, Rcpp::const_iterator)'`

If I try just `return wrap(x(0, 5));` it compiles, but R crashes at runtime.

I have been unable to find any code samples that I could get to work as expected.

So I have a simpler goals now. I am trying to replicate the following basic R commands with Rcpp:

```
x[1,]
           [,1]
2000-01-02    1
x[,1]  # The entire column.
x[1:5,1:1]
           [,1]
2000-01-02    1
2000-01-03    2
2000-01-04    3
2000-01-05    4
2000-01-06    5
```

With the dates and other xts attributes intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily because the deparsing of `"2000-02-05 00:00:00/2000-03-10 00:00:00"` is done in a fairly extensive bit of *R* code in the `xts` package which you would have to duplicate.

But fear not. You can still parse dates, find a begin and end and use that to subset.  What I most often was to treat the timestamp that is `POSIXct` (or `Rcpp::Datetime`) as a numeric variable, and pass the `xts` "index" column down as a numeric too.

There is also a C-level interface to `xts`, and I recently updated [the header file defining it](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/blob/master/inst/include/xtsAPI.h) in a PR.

Comment: I actually have the index values I need or the actual times in seconds. However I still cannot get a submatrix to work. How would I subset with the time values? Thank you.

Comment: Simplify. At the end of the day a timestamp is a double. So is the index. So find that the values greater (or equal, depends of your definition) than the start value and smaller than the end.  Just because `xts` offers it at the R prompt does _not_ imply existence of an equivalent C++ API, sadly.